# Can't pass kwargs to sub class in Kivy -- TypeError: object.__init__() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize)

Tags: python, kivy, subclass, init

I'm very new to programming so forgive me if the solution here is obvious. I've done a fair bit of googling and haven't been able to sort this problem out.
I'm trying to enable a subclass to accept any keyword arguments the base class can accept, as well as a few additional ones I want to pass, but I keep running into the following error: TypeError: object.**init**() takes exactly one argument (the instance to initialize).

If I comment out the keyword arguments not built into the base class (workout_title, last_completed, and lifts) the code runs no problem.

How do I allow the subclass to take my additional kwargs?

```
class SelectionBanner(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    
        grid = GridLayout(
            rows = 3, 
            size_hint = (.8,1)
            )
        workout_title_label = Label(
            size_hint = (1,.33), 
            pos_hint = {"top": 1, "left": .5}, 
            text = "workout tile"
            )
        last_completed_label = Label(
            size_hint = (1,.33), 
            pos_hint = {"top": 1, "left": .5}, 
            text = "last_completed"
            )
        lifts_label = Label(
            size_hint = (1,.33), 
            pos_hint = {"top": 1, "left": .5}, 
            text = "lifts"
            )
        button = Button(
            size_hint = (.2, 1),
            text = "Click me!"
        )

        grid.add_widget(workout_title_label)
        grid.add_widget(last_completed_label)
        grid.add_widget(lifts_label)
    
        self.add_widget(grid)
        self.add_widget(button)

def build_selection_page(self):
    data = db.reference("/workout_templates").get()
    selection_page = self.root.ids['home_screen'].ids['top_layout']
    selection_page.add_widget(SelectionBanner(
        cols = 2, 
        padding = 10, 
        spacing = 10, 
        pos_hint = {"top": 1, "left": .5}, 
        size_hint = (1, .2),
        workout_title = "Workout B",
        last_completed = "Yesterday",
        lifts = "Bench and stuff"
        ))
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback. And if most of that code isn't necessary for the error, create a test file that doesn't have it. Make it easy to copy and run your code.

Comment: What does _"If I comment out the keyword arguments not built into the base class (workout_title, last_completed, and lifts) the code runs no problem."_ mean? Are you instantiating the class with arguments like this?

Comment: tdelaney, thank you for the feedback on effective question posting. This was my first post so that's helpful feedback for going forward.

John Anderson's suggestion below fixed my problem, but to answer your question I was instantiating the class as seen in the build_selection_page function. When done with the last three arguments (my added kwargs that are not handled already by the base class) it threw the type error. But if I removed those arguments it worked just fine.

Comment: Got it. I must not have copied enough of the code when I tried to duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `Properties` for the new keyword arguments, like this:

```
class SelectionBanner(GridLayout):
    workout_title = StringProperty('')
    last_completed = StringProperty('')
    lifts = StringProperty('')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    .
    .
    .
```